# Библиотеки для работы с графиками функций

Tags: java, javafx, поиск-библиотек

Нужна библиотека для постройки графиков функций аля sin x, cos x^2, 2x^2+3x+4 и т.д., стандартная LineChart в JavaFX показалась мне жутко неудобной, в ней нету механизма масштабирования, непонятно как построить кастомные графики, как сделать функцию не из отрезков, а из прямых, то-есть что бы график не останавливался на некой точке. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.awt.*;javax.swing.*;
Вы можете масштабировать оси координат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]